# Merging different alembic revision heads fails on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, alembic

I'm working to modify a [cookiecutter](https://github.com/wdm0006/cookiecutter-flask) Flask app.

locally I have deleted the migration folder and sqllite db a couple of times during development. I've pushed my chnages to heroku.

When trying to migrate the heroku postgresdb :

```
$ heroku run python manage.py db upgrade
.....
alembic.util.CommandError: Multiple head revisions are present for given argument 'head'; please specify a specific target revision, '<branchname>@head' to narrow to a specific head, or 'heads' for all heads
```

following http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/branches.html I tried:

```
$ heroku run python manage.py db merge heads
Running python manage.py db merge heads on myapp... up, run.9635
  Generating /app/migrations/versions/35888775_.py ... done
```

Then I tried:

```
$ heroku run python manage.py db upgrade
Running python manage.py db upgrade on myapp... up, run.7021
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
    ....
    "%s@head" % branch_label if branch_label else "head")
alembic.util.CommandError: Multiple head revisions are present for given argument 'head'; please specify a specific target revision, '<branchname>@head' to narrow to a specific head
, or 'heads' for all heads
```

How can I merge the revision heads into one and make sure this is synced with my development version?

Answer (score 0):

I contacted heroku support and got the following back (which worked for me):

Hi,

To remove a folder from your local repository, git rm needs to be run. Could you please try something like below?

```
$ git rm -r migrations
$ git commit -m 'Remove migrations directory'
$ git push heroku master
```

To see differences between actual files and what are registered onto your local repository, git status may be useful.

Please let us know if you have any difficulty here.